# How to choose slash and assemble file path in ruby?

Tags: ruby

In Windows OS, back slash `\` is used in file path (`c:\mytext.txt`). In linux/unix OS, forward slash `/` is used in file path (`/home/mytext.txt`). Given a dir path `file_dir` and `file_name`, how to find the right `slash` for the OS and assemble the file path (OS could be either Windows or Linux)? `file_dir + '/' + file name` Or `file_dir + '\' + file_name`? Any escape for slash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [IO documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/IO.html#method-c-select):

> Ruby will convert pathnames between different operating system conventions if possible. For instance, on a Windows system the filename "/gumby/ruby/test.rb" will be opened as "\gumby\ruby\test.rb". When specifying a Windows-style filename in a Ruby string, remember to escape the backslashes:

```
"c:\\gumby\\ruby\\test.rb"
```

So, don't make more work for yourself. Use forward-slashes for clarity and to remove the leaning-toothpick syndrome strings.

If you *need* to know what path delimiter to use, there's always `File::ALT_SEPARATOR` but messing with it or writing code accessing it directly instead of letting Ruby do the right thing is seldom needed. All the File methods doing joins and splits honor `File::ALT_SEPARATOR` already.

> [...] File::ALT_SEPARATOR can be used to get the platform-specific separator character.

Comment: `When specifying a Windows-style filename in a Ruby string, remember to escape the backslashes:` Our development is Windows and hosting is ubuntu. Is `file_path.gsub('\', '\\')` going to do the work? This is a little painful if we have to find out if the path is Windows style and added backslashs.

Comment: you can always just use single quotes ie, `path = 'C:\gumby\ruby\test.rb' to avoid escaping at all.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`File.join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-join) which is OS agnostic:

```
File.join("my", "dir", "and", "my", "file")
#=> my\dir\and\my\file for Windows
#=> my/dir/and/my/file for unix
```

Comment: And be prepared for the multi-platform development pain! :)

Comment: File.join always starts from the root which may not be correct if the file is not saved under web root.

Comment: @user938363 you could use `File.expand_path` to create relative path. Also it the question was just about slashes ;)

Comment: `File.join` does not "always start at the root." It starts with whatever the first argument is. (`File.expand_path` is a great method, though, and underrated as too few people know how to use it with the second argument.)

Comment: User may specify a path which is out of the web root.

Comment: @JordanRunning I wish they'd rather stay that way. Relative paths with the base path following the relative path? That's pretty much unreadable, especially when used extensively with different base paths to require files. Especially with `__FILE__` as the base path. I think using paths relative to a project root is a better option. And `expand_path()` is not really of much help in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby uses `/` as the path separator for both Windows and Unix systems:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> irb
irb(main):001:0> Dir.pwd
=> "C:/Users/Administrator"
irb(main):002:0> File.join(Dir.pwd,'testing.txt')
=> "C:/Users/Administrator/testing.txt"
irb(main):003:0> File.read(File.join(Dir.pwd,'testing.txt'))
=> "foo bar"
```

So if you really wanted to use a string you can do something like this as well:

```
irb(main):004:0> File.read('C:/Users/Administrator/testing.txt')
=> "foo bar"
```